# Negative regex in splunk (not using fields)

Tags: splunk

Without extracting fields, I want to search for any events that do not contain "country=$", i.e. the event must not end with "country=". I can regex it to "country=(?!$)", but that still requires country to be present in the event, which is not what I want.

Example:
my search:

```
source=*vhost* | regex "country=(?!$)"
```

events:

```
language=en&country=&playerId=29539105

language=en&country=

general error
```

I want to exclude the middle one, while still hitting the other two. I can do it in regular regex evaluators, but splunk doesn't seem to read regex the same way.

In a regular regex interpreter, I've matched that it is enough with (?!(country=$)), but splunk doesn't understand this, and hits all events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found one solution to the problem, if not regex-specific:

```
regex _raw!="country=$"
```